# How to create a small SPARQL query for DBpedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm a SPARQL beginner, I would like to know how to create this small query in SPARQL from DBpedia:

The query is: Getting the topics of a thing (name of person, organisation …)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?occupation WHERE {
  ?s <w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>; 'Madonna'@en . ?occupation dbpedia-owl:occupation ?s 
}
```

So I create this query to get the occupation of Madonna, is this correct? In this case Madonna but it could be anything else.

I tried this query but i think this is wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?occupation WHERE { 
  ?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> 'Madonna'@en .
  ?s dbpedia-owl:occupation ?occupation
}
```

I tried this too i think it's correct:

```
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?string 
WHERE {
  res:Tom_Cruise dbpprop:occupation ?string .
}
```

It works with `Tom_Cruise` but not with `Madonna` or `barack_Obama` for example.

Comment: There are lots of examples already here on StackOverflow. E.g., if you search for [dbpedia and sparql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sparql+dbpedia) you'll find 236 questions tagged.

Comment: To find out what sort of data there is about the kinds of things you're interested in, visit the DBpedia page for the thing, e.g., http://dbpedia.org/page/Stack_Overflow and you'll see what kind of data is available.

Comment: I already wrote the thing that i want to be returned by dbpedia. In fact i need the topic of a thing. This thing could be person, organisation... it's a named entity in general. SO the user could write for example madonna, so i must create a query that return to me the topic of madonna in dbpedia which is "artist".

Comment: The data on Madonna is visible at http://dbpedia.org/page/Madonna_(entertainer) . Do you mean that you want the values of the dcterms:subject property (there are a bunch though, and none are simply "Artist") or the values of the rdf:type property (again, there a bunch, but dbpedia-owl:Artist is one of the values)?

Comment: In the question, you've also asked for "name of person, organsation", which are not really "topics of a thing".  Take a look at the Madonna page I mentioned in the previous comment.  If you can select exactly which information you want to get back from a query (but please do that by updating the question, not responding in a comment), then the question will be much clearer, and it will be much easier to provide a working answer.

Comment: No, i did not asked for name of person. The name will be in the query,  so i will ask dbpedia what is the occupation of this person. or the type in this case will be dbpedia-owl:Artist That's all what i need. the query could be sent using any named entity for example:  madonna, Apple, microsoft, Mercedes, Ronaldo... It's very simple query, but i'm a beginner, i want to know this query to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood you;  I didn't find "Getting the topics of a thing (name of person, organisation...)" particularly clear.  As I said, please, as an example, visit http://dbpedia.org/page/Madonna_(entertainer) and update the question with the particular results from that page that you'd like to retrieve by using a SPARQL query.  That will clarify for us and for future readers what _exactly_ it is that you're trying to do, and it will give us a specific question that we can answer clearly.

Comment: I agree that your question probably has a simple answer, but there are lots of questions with simple answers, and it's not clear what which one is _your_ question.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT  ?occupation WHERE { 
 ?s <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> 'Madonna'@en .
 ?occupation dbpedia-owl:occupation ?s


 } so i create this query to get the occupation of madonna, is this correct? In this case madonna but it could be anything else.

Comment: Because it's next to impossible to read code in comments, I asked in an earlier comment that you post that as an update/edit to the question, and not as a comment.  You're on the right track though.  In this case you could use a query like the one shown in, and get the results shown in http://pastebin.com/ruPh4fZf .

Comment: Yes, i upadated the question.

Comment: I explained everything in a new answer , please help.

Comment: Please dont' post comments as answers.  If you're providing more information that should have been in the question, then _edit_ the question (there's an edit link under the question).

Answer (score 3):

A query like your attempt is a good start:

```
PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?string 
WHERE {
  res:Tom_Cruise dbpprop:occupation ?string .
}
```

Now that we've got something specific to work from, we can look at the specific problems that it might have.  First, I'm going to rewrite it using the same namespace prefixes that the public endpoint web interface supports, so that we can copy and paste to it.  I'm also putting the keywords in lower case because I don't like yelling.

```
select distinct ?string where {
  dbpedia:Tom_Cruise dbpprop:occupation ?string .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?string%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aTom_Cruise%20dbpprop%3aoccupation%20?string%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Now, you mentioned that

> It works with `Tom_Cruise` but not with `Madonna` or `barack_Obama`, for example.

All the data in DBpedia is publicly available for you to browse.  If you want to see why there are no results for `Madonna`, note that `dbpedia:Madonna` is shorthand for http://dbpedia.org/resource/Madonna and pull up that page in your browser.  From the properties listed on that page, you'll see that it's a redirection page (indeed, you'll see the same thing if you go to the corresponding Wikipedia article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madonna).  You want the IRI http://dbpedia.org/resource/Madonna_(entertainer).  Unfortunately, you can't write that directly in a SPARQL query because of the parentheses, so you have to write

```
select distinct ?string where {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Madonna_(entertainer)> dbpprop:occupation ?string .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?string%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Madonna_%28entertainer%29%3E%20dbpprop%3aoccupation%20?string%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Now, there are a couple of problems with `barack_Obama`:  (i) the capitalization needs to be `Barack_Obama` if you want any results.  If you visit http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama, though, you'll see that there's no `dbpprop:occupation` property.  There's not much you can do about that;  you can't query for data that isn't there.  The data that *is* there that might be useful to you (and of a similar nature) would be `dbpedia-owl:office`, and `dbpedia-owl:profession`.  For instance

```
select distinct ?string where {
  dbpedia:Barack_Obama (dbpedia-owl:office|dbpedia-owl:profession) ?string .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?string%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aBarack_Obama%20%28dbpedia-owl%3aoffice%7Cdbpedia-owl%3aprofession%29%20?string%20.%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Is there any solution to make that automatic? I mean how i know if i must use Madonna or Madonna_(Entertainer) ? Knowing that a page for Madonna exist: http://dbpedia.org/page/Madonna How can i do for this by sparql query?